# Pattern to 'feed' database rows to an interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The problem is simple: fetch rows from a database and pass them to an interface. F.e. one implementation of this interface will write this data to an XML file.

I'm looking for a pattern so:

- the interface only has one method instead of 3: `beginWrite` / `write` / `endWrite`
- it shouldn't fetch all rows at once, but instead 'feed' the interface row-by-row.
- I don't want to pass the mongodb cursor to the interface, because interface implementation should not rely on a specific database driver.

**Interface**

```
function IBackend(implementation){
    // removed code that merges implementation with this interface
    // because it is irrelevant to this question.
}

IBackend.prototype.beginWrite = function(callback) {};

IBackend.prototype.write = function(row, callback) {};

IBackend.prototype.endWrite = function(callback) {};
```

**Idea**

Something I came up with was to only define one function:

```
IBackend.prototype.writeAll = function(callback) {};
```

then the implementation of this interface calls the `callback` passing a `writeOne` and `end` callback as arguments so it can be used as:

```
backend.writeAll(function(writeOneCallback, endCallback) {
    collection.find().each(function(err, doc){
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
        writeOneCallback(doc);
    });
    endCallback();
});
```

But then, the passing of the `writeOne` and `end` callback depends on the implementation and isn't specified in the interface. So if anyone knows an elegant solution for this, I would love to hear it :)

Comment: Why does it need to be an "interface"? That's not a common pattern in NodeJs app APIs.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: we have different backend implementations that all need to implement the same interface. By constructing an interface we can verify the completeness of the implementation at compile time.

Comment: Compile time? Aren't we talking JavaScript? You just need a function that has the right parameters when used as a callback. Anything else really feels unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Sorry, I meant run-time.

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. Your second solution seems to adequately solve your problem. You seem to be trying to force JavaScript to do something it wasn't intended to do. You could check the function signature, but I don't see what that will gain you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is streams. While it has more than method, and as such doesn't answer your question, it  is:

1. Proven
2. Seems appropriate
3. Plays nicely with many other parts of the node.js ecosystem
4. Doesn't need all rows at once, e.g.

There are also many streams already available that will reduce your development time, and many other streams you can pipe your stream's output to that will also reduce dev time (xml, zip, send over http, etc.).

See the excellent Streams Handbook (https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) for more, and examples of such "other streams".

If you are still not convinced, I can think of only 2 scenarios:

1. Your interface also guarantees that the implementation does not need to be "flushed" (that is: does not maintain a state between calls to `write()` that will eventually need to be summarized, flushed, output, etc. Examples of such states: buffers, stats that will be appended/prepended to the output, ...).
2. Your interface does not guarantee that.

If #1 above is correct, then simply have `write()`, that accepts either an array of rows of a single row, and does the processing immediately. The guarantee by #1 above implies that at any given moment, the output from your interface constitutes a valid, coherent state.

If #2 above is correct (as would be the example for outputting an XML file), then I don't see a way around at least `write()` and `end()`.

Comment: I already checked out [node.js streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). I can JSON serialize rows and put them on a String-stream, but there is no guarantee that `read` will read a complete JSON object from the stream. Maybe I need to implement my own Object stream or something like that...

Comment: Oops, seems like I overlooked the [Object mode](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode) of those streams! That might fit my needs.